# Visual Studio Performance Profiler not showing up

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I recently downloaded Visual Studio Community 2015. I mostly make Windows Forms applications. When I first downloaded Community and ran my programs, the Performance profiler showed up every time but now it won't show up. I need to monitor the CPU usage. How do I get the Performance profiler to pop up when I debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably closed Diagnostics Tools window while debugging, so now it does not show up (which is a standard behavior for tool windows). To make it show up please invoke "Debug > Show Diagnostic Tools" or hit Ctrl + Alt + F2 while debugging.