# Performance Profiler does not show up

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

My Profiler does not show up when I click on it.
[image: love]

According to [Visual Studio Performance Profiler not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010638/visual-studio-performance-profiler-not-showing-up) it might be due to the closed Diagnostic Tools, but in my case they are open.
I can debug and track CPU Usage/Memory Usage. But I need to start the Profiler itself.

I already tried resetting the window layout as well as **reinstalling VS completely**

Running `devenv /Log`
Shows only these things related to the performance profiler:
[image]
[Full Log](https://pastebin.com/ThazBQmh)

Comment: It's probably a tab in a minimized pane or some other hidden control. Can you reset the layout?

Comment: Already tried. Nothing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/log-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022

Comment: @HansPassant Added relevant Log sections

Comment: The packages loaded correctly, no errors reported.  Try it in a new dummy solution to ensure it isn't caused by corrupt IDE data (hidden .vs folder).

Comment: @HansPassant does not open on a new project aswell

Comment: Does the same problem occur with other versions of Visual Studio?

Comment: It happens on VS2022 and VS2019

Comment: Any third-party plugins used? It looks like a bug.

Comment: I have the newest updates installed, no Extensions

Comment: You could report the problem to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp/report)